# find all strings in string array from another string in a specific order mvc

Tags: linq, model-view-controller

for example I have this strings in an array:

```
var name = new string[] { "john", "a", "doe" };
```

and these list of names:

```
var names = new List<string>() { "John Alias Doe", "Johnny Dude Doe", "Jane Gal Doe", "John Wick A. Doe" };
```

The result would not include "Johnny Dude Doe" because there is no 'a' in his name between "John" and "Doe".

I'm using MVC and linq. currently I'm using this:

```
var nameresults = names.Where(ns => name.All(n => ns.Contains(n))).ToList();
```

Comment: So, based on your 'name' and your 'nameresults' list's, could you provide a sample of what you would EXPECT to see from your query result? I feel like there is more to this question than originally meets the eye. Are you trying to do a conditional match, like you want to obtain all of the names where the first word has 'john', and the second word has 'a', and the third word has doe?

Comment: What you ask me kinda explains it too, but if this may help, I want all the names with first name as "John" and last names with "Doe", and the "A" should appear anywhere between "John" and "Doe" whether it is in the middle name or also in the first name, example if the first is "John Paul D. Doe". My only problem is that the names are in a single string and separated as firstname, middle and lastname. I don't know if this helps and if what I want to happen is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var targetName = new List<string>() { "John", "A", "Doe" };
var namesToSearch = new List<string>() { "John Alias Doe", "Johnny Dude Doe", "Jane Gal Doe", "John Wick A. Doe" };

var results = namesToSearch.Where(x => targetName.All(y => x.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

String search is case sensitive which may be all that is wrong with your code.

If you want it to work in a case insensitive way then change the query to:

```
var targetName = new List<string>() { "john", "a", "doe" };
var namesToSearch = new List<string>() { "John Alias Doe", "Johnny Dude Doe", "Jane Gal Doe", "John Wick A. Doe" };

var results = namesToSearch.Where(x => targetName.All(y => x.ToLower().Contains(y.ToLower()))).ToList();
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to approach this particular problem from a linq-only approach, however, this will do what you are trying to achieve properly.

```
        string[] matchArray = new string[] { "john", "a", "doe" };
        List<string> namesToCheck = new List<string>() { "John Alias Doe", "Johnny Dude Doe", "Jane Gal Doe", "John Wick A. Doe" };

        List<string> matchedNames = new List<string>(), notMatchedNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (string name in namesToCheck) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name.Trim())) { //invalid string
                continue;
            }

            if (!name.Contains(" ")) { // potentially missing middle and last names... handle this how you want
                continue;
            }

            string[] nameSegments = name.Split(' ');

            bool nameIsInProperFormat = nameSegments.Length >= 3;

            if (!nameIsInProperFormat) {
                continue; // for now continue, you will need to handle this?
            }

            string firstName = nameSegments[0],
                lastName = nameSegments[nameSegments.Length - 1],
                middleName = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 1; i < nameSegments.Length - 1; i++) {
                middleName += nameSegments[i];
            }

            bool firstNameMeetsCriteria = firstName.ToUpper().Contains(matchArray[0].ToUpper());
            bool middleNameMeetsCriteria = middleName.ToUpper().Contains(matchArray[1].ToUpper());
            bool lastNameMeetsCriteria = lastName.ToUpper().Contains(matchArray[2].ToUpper());

            if (firstNameMeetsCriteria &&
                middleNameMeetsCriteria &&
                lastNameMeetsCriteria) {
                matchedNames.Add(name);
            }
            else {
                notMatchedNames.Add(name);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Matched Names:");
        foreach (string matchedName in matchedNames) {
            Console.WriteLine(matchedName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Not Matched Names:");
        foreach (string notFoundName in notMatchedNames) {
            Console.WriteLine(notFoundName);
        }
```

Output:

```
        Matched Names:
            John Alias Doe
            John Wick A. Doe


        Not Matched Names:
            Johnny Dude Doe
            Jane Gal Doe
```